# Why is Gorm not returning results with Rows()?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have tried this with .Rows() and .Scan(). I do not understand why .Rows has this log

SELECT TOP(100) * from person[] 0

and .Scan has this

SELECT TOP(100) * from person[] 100

The results from scan store the value properly in the struct. The results from scanRows stores nothing in the struct.

Here is my code snippet

```
if table.ResultsPerPage > 0{
    getDB().Raw("SELECT TOP(100) * from person").Scan(rowContainer) //dynamic struct
    rows, err := getDB().Raw("SELECT TOP(100) * from person").Rows()
    if err != nil {
        return err, nil
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    rowCount := 0
    for rowCount< table.ResultsPerPage {
        if(!rows.Next()){
            break
        }
        if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
            return err, nil
        }

        err = getDB().ScanRows(rows, &rowContainer) // dynamic struct
        if err != nil {
            return err, nil
        }
        rowCount++
    }
```

Comment: I want to use rows since I don't want everything in memory at the same time. Scan works fine and returns everything. Rows works kinda, it has rows.Next() return true. But the contents of it only contain the table headers. Where is the data?

Comment: One thing that is weird is I don't need the & when doing scan, but I get a panic unaddressable value if I leave it off of scanRows

Answer (score 1):

`Scan()` fetches all rows at once potentially consuming a lot of memory. `Scan()` knows how many rows will be fetched because it just fetched them all. `Scan()` takes a slice to put structs into.

`Rows()` provides an iterator so you can fetch them one at a time ensuring memory use remains constant. `Rows()` does not know how many rows will be fetched. `ScanRows()` should be given a struct, not a slice.

If you need all the rows in memory at once, use `Scan()`. If you only need them one at a time, use `Rows().`

Comment: I can't get any rows to return from rows(). Nothing at all, but scan works fine and returns them all. I don't want to return them all, just 1 at a time.

Comment: Correction, it returns rows with rows.Next() which returns true. But there is no data in it, it appears only the column names are there.

Comment: @coloradoman After `getDB().ScanRows(rows, &rowContainer)` the row data should be in `rowContainer`. However, you're using `rowContainer` for both `ScanRows` which fetches one row and `Scan` which fetches multiple rows. What is `rowContainer`?

Comment: It is a slice of the dynamic struct that represents the data coming from this select. I have a feeling that the &rowContainer isn't what I want to do.

Comment: What I am trying to do is just convert that struct to a csv anyways. I am using gocsv https://github.com/gocarina/gocsv. But it only accepts a slice as the argument for making the .csv

Comment: @coloradoman Try using a plain struct, not a slice.

Comment: Yes I have just tried this and now I am getting some data. The problem now is how to convert this "row" to a csv string. Any ideas? My gocsv won't let me since it needs to be a slice for it to work.

Comment: @coloradoman You should ask that as a new question.

Comment: thanks for your help. I just ended up writting my own csv creator. But changing that & was the big reason it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

If you notices rowContainer is actually a slice since in scan it is able to put multiple rows into it. I had to use &rowContainer for it not to throw a seg fault. This is the incorrect method to do this. To fix this, I just used a struct and not a slice of structs for .rows()